# How did Odin give or lose the Tesseract?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

I'm confused about how the Tesseract can be in *Thor* if it was lost 600 years ago, as I know Asgard gave up the red Infinity Stone because they already had another Infinity Stone. What's going on?

Comment: https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/T%C3%B8nsberg

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: In fact, the tesseract was lost for 1147 years! from 965 to 2012

Answer (score 9):

The question is imprecise, as you didn't properly tag or indicate the *Thor* movie you are referencing. However, I believe you are talking about *Thor: Ragnarok*, where Hela passes by the Tesseract while pillaging Odin's vault.

The Tesseract was brought back by Thor in *The Avengers*, while also bringing Loki into custody. The Tesseract was thus locked in Odin's vault along with other artefacts. Later on, in *Thor: The Dark World*, the Asgardians manage to capture the entirety of the Ether; but they decide to entrust **The Collector** with it. They refuse to keep two Infinity Stones together because of the sheer dangerousness of the Stones.

Thus the Tesseract is kept within Odin's vault until *Thor: Ragnarok*, where it is stolen by Loki when escaping Asgard. Finally, Thanos comes to take it by force in *Avengers: Infinity War*.

For the record, the Tesseract does appear in the first *Thor* movie, in the stinger only. It was recovered by Howard Stark from the bottom of the ocean (where it landed in *Captain America: The First Avenger*) and given to the top-secret Project PEGASUS to be studied extensively. In Thor's stinger, a brain-washed Erik Selvig participates in Project PEGASUS while under Loki's influence, which directly ties into Avengers' opening sequence.

Comment: I believe that he confused *Thor* with *Captain America: the First Avenger*

Comment: @PeregrineLennert in this case, since Captain America happened before Thor, we can only assume the Tesseract was given to humanity as a gift by the Asgardians, because it was kept in a religious mural. But this is at best a guess ; Marvel (in)famously likes to avoid explaining the relationship between Norse mythology and MCU!Asgardians.

Comment: @Caelistis I believe Odin lost the Tesseract on Earth(Norway to be exact) during the battle with the Frost Giants. It was then found by Red Skull at the beginning of TFA.